# How to Write a new file from retrieved text from Read File and new stuff in it

Tags: c#

The text i am reading from has a couple lines.
I want to add new lines to it such as date, cost, intro.
I think I can manually enter it but I would like to know if it is possible to read each line and print it into the new file along with the new inputs on separate lines. Would like to use stream reader and stream writer still as it seems the simplest one I could find online.
The only thing it seems to print is: System.IO.StreamReader

```
        //WRITE FILE
        public void writeFile()
        {

            GroceryItem readGroceryList = new GroceryItem();

            string[] lines = { "Grocery for you", Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now), readFile()  };
            StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("c:\\MicrosoftVisual\\invoice.txt");
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                file.WriteLine(line);
                file.Flush();
            }
        }

        public string readFile() // to adjust name of method later if require
        {
            //READ FILE
            StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader("groceries.txt");
            string consoleLine = "";
            while (consoleLine != null)
            {
                consoleLine = myReader.ReadLine();
                if (consoleLine != null)
                {
                    return Convert.ToString(myReader);
                }
            }
            return consoleLine;
        }

        public GroceryItem (string n, double p)
```

Comment: Note that Visual Studio is an integrated development. It doesn't execute your code. Is there a specific problem you're having with your current approach?

Comment: Not very clear, You wants to write the text of this file to new file adding extra information?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendtext?view=netframework-4.7.2
The File.AppendText method should work for what you ask?

Comment: What do you expect to happen? `return Convert.ToString(myReader);` is the source of your problem, but it's not clear what exactly you're trying to do. Should `readFile()` return all of the lines? Depending on what you want, it would be better to use `File.ReadAllLines` or `File.ReadAllText`.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem lies in the `readFile` method. I think your intension is to read all lines and not just one line and then return your reader as string. To do this I would collect all the lines in a `List<string>` and return that, like so:

```cs
public List<string> ReadFile()
{
    StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader("groceries.txt");
    List<string> list = new List<string>(); // Create an empty list of strings
    while (myReader.Peek() >= 0) // Checks if the stream has reacht the end of the file.
    {
        list.Add(myReader.ReadLine()); // Reads a line out of the files and appends it to the list.
    }
    return list; // Returns the list from the method.
}
```

With these changes you also need to adjust your `writeFile` method, like so:

```cs
public void WriteFile()
{
    List<string> lines = ReadFile();
    // Calls ReadFile to get the already exsisting lines from the file.
    lines.Add("Grocery for you"); // You can add new lines now.
    lines.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString());
    StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("c:\\MicrosoftVisual\\invoice.txt");
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        file.WriteLine(line);
    }
    file.Flush(); // You only need to call Flush once when you are finished writing to the Stream.
}
```

There is even a simpler variant without `Stream`s by using C#'s `File` helper class.

```cs
List<string> lines = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines("groceries.txt"));
// Reads all lines from the file and puts them into the list.
lines.Add("Grocery for you"); // You can add new lines now.
lines.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString());
File.WriteAllLines("c:\\MicrosoftVisual\\invoice.txt", lines);
```

Comment: thanks alot! that worked, i made a new foreach and string cus i could not find a way to add the grocery and date to the top, now I am just going to try figuring out how to use the values within the read file to use in my calculation methods, without entering it into the code if that's possible